# C# Linq one to many query EF Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table of checkbox items and a table that stores the users selected checkbox items. The watered down model is essentially like this in EF

CheckboxItem Model Properties:

```
public CheckboxItem()
{
    SelectedCheckboxItems = new HashSet<SelectedCheckboxItems>
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<SelectedCheckboxItems> SelectedCheckboxItems { get; set; }
```

SelectedCheckboxItems Model Properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public virtual Checkbox Checkbox { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to grab all available checkbox items along with their corresponding selected checkbox items and shove them into a viewmodel that I'll be using later on to populate the View with the correct checkboxes/pre-select their selected choices.

I've got a working solution so far but the query is slow it takes around 4-5 seconds for the query to complete:

```
 var testSub = _context.CheckboxItem.Include(a => a.SelectedCheckboxItems).Where(a => a...// filters)
                .Select(a => new ViewModel
            {
                CheckboxItemId = a.Id,
                Checked = a.SelectedCheckboxItems.Where(x => x.userId.Equals(userId) && x.Id == a.Id).Select(z => z.Checked == true).FirstOrDefault()
            }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

The end goal is to really just return a list of ViewModel objects with all the available checkbox items and whether that item has been selected by the user or not.

Any tips on how to improve upon this or optimize this in any way so that it would be a lot quicker? The table really only has like 15 available checkbox items so it just feels rather sluggish for this query to finish in 4-5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Change ToList() to AsQueryable(). ToList() causes slower performance.

How about this?

```
var selectedlist = db.SelectedCheckboxItems;
    var testSub = _context.CheckboxItem.Where(a => a...// filters)
    .Select(a => new ViewModel {
                CheckboxItemId = a.Id,
                Checked = selectedlist.Where(x => x.userId.Equals(userId) && x.Id == a.Id).Select(z => z.Checked == true).FirstOrDefault()
            }).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
```